# Understanding the meaning of different standard deviations from different values

Tags: standard-deviation, frequency

**Disclaimer:** Before I stated the question, I should say that I'm very new at the area of statistics and the understanding of its application. So I ask you people to please be patient with me because I'm trying to learn about this wonderful world.

---

**Question**: I have a table of test grades from some year where more than 10,000 students took the exam. It goes as follows:

```
| Test Grade    | Standard Deviation    | 
|---------------|-----------------------| 
| 272.891526    | 29.494996             | 
| 240.767634    | 42.557313             | 
| 375.347864    | 15.259388             |
```

Since each student receives **different tests** from a pile of content, each grade is calculated through some scores which reflect the probability that he/she has some set of skills. **For example**: If student **A** gets $250$+, he/she probably understand how to calculate the average term of a sequence.

What I'm trying to understand is: How can I **analyse the groups** of students in this whole set of grades **taking into account the standard deviation?** Are one properly way to doing so or it depends of "where I'm going with this data?"

If all these results on **Test Grade** had $100\%$ probability of being right, I would only need then to separate the students into proper categories. But in this case, student **A** and student **B** may have the same grade, but different **standard deviations**.

I honestly don't expect a full detailed answer, but something to guide me through this problem.

Comment: "Analyze" is a generic word: it hasn't any specific meaning.  Thus, you need to explain the objective of your analysis.  It would help to explain what each line of the table refers to: is it one form of the test?  A group of students?  One student?  If it's for one student per line, exactly what is the "standard deviation" based on?

Comment: **Is it one form of the test?**

It is a single exam. The database of questions contains a fixed set of questions called **Incomplete Balanced Blocks**, and the ones that each student will receive are picking some what randomly. In practice, it means that student **A** may receive 2 questions about "area of a triangle", while student **B** receives only one and student **C** none. <br/>

Comment: **A group of students?**

The exam is taken by a group of people on school, with similar age and similar backgroud education

Comment: **If it's for one student per line, exactly what is the "standard deviation" based on?**

Given the results of the exams, is made a metric which will tell us the probability that the students can understand the topics charged in the test based on a proficiency scale. The student receives a score, which goes from $0$ to $500$. So, given the sample of students, with a specifc score on the proficiency scale, it is assigned a standard deviation from the score that this student received. This value is weighted on several aspects, such as the block that the student received.

Comment: In this case, as far as I can understand, the standard deviation is a way of seeing how good our prediction on the population is, given our sample and the metrics that we used. Am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, your question is kind of unclear. You've clarifed some of it in your comments, but it would be better to edit your question to include all the information. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for all the clarifications.  There's still one sticking point: it's hard to see how an objective answer to your question could be formulated without knowing exactly what these standard deviations are and how they are computed.  Some very strong assumptions and a specific model are required to assign a "standard deviation" (understood broadly as some measure of uncertainty or variability) to an individual score.

Comment: I see. I totally understand what you two are explaining to me. Well, seeing what whuber said, I can see that I need to jump deep in the meaning of standard deviation in this case, the metrics and how they were able to create such values. From that I will be able to make my own objective questions and get some good answers for this data set. Thanks